# telnet to the local Sagemcom F@st 5260 router returns "Connection refused"

Tags: router, telnet

I have a router "Sagemcom F@st 5260"

If I run `telnet 192.168.1.1` from any local machine, then I get

"telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.1: Connection refused

telnet: Unable to connect to remote host"

My question: How do I fix it?

I have my router from the internet provider, maybe they preconfigure it somehow. Or, I wonder, if some routers just don't support telnet? I can login to the router settings in browser going to http://192.168.1.1/

That's the menu that I can see:

[image]

And that's the menu inside access control:

[image]

Could anyone please help and point me to any possible reasons why I can't telnet to my router?

Comment: If you *"want to play with router CLI"* (and aren't concerned about the product warranty), you could open up the device and look for a (TTL) serial port connection/header that might get you console access.

Comment: @sawdust, could you elaborate? what are my actions once I have serial port connection/header?

Comment: On the circuit board, look for a 3 or 4-pin header (or solder-filled holes), e.g. https://pogoplughacking.blogspot.com/2017/12/pogoplug-pogo-v4-a1-01-serial-pinout.html  Connect a USB-to-3volt_TTL_serial adapter, e.g. https://www.adafruit.com/product/954  Try COM settings of 115200-8N1.  Hopefully you can get a Linux login prompt.  You will need a valid username & password to get into the system console, unless it is unprotected.  Once logged in, you would have a Linux shell prompt, similar to desktop Linux but with a reduced command set.  See https://hackaday.com/tag/serial-port/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router doesn't support telnet. Most don't. I don't see any mention of telnet in its user manual.

Telnet is a security risk, because it is not encrypted. Some routers support SSH instead, but even that is fairly rare. Vendors don't want the tech support hassle of full shell access, and providing shell access or a custom CLI doesn't help sell more routers (except maybe a few models targeted toward geeks).

If you want telnet or SSH access, upgrade to aftermarket Linux based router firmware like OpenWrt or DD-WRT, etc., if you can find a distro that supports your model.

Comment: yeah, actually I don't necessarily need telnet, but rather wan to play with router CLI. @spiff, I have a noob question: "if you can find a distro that supports your model" -> can you please elaborate on that, what do you mean here?


I'm surprised to learn that most of the routers don't support any CLI.  do you think that "NETGEAR Nighthawk Smart WiFi Router (R6700)" wouldn't support it either?

thank you. I'll accept your answer tomorrow

Comment: When someone packages up and distributes some form of the GNU/Linux operating system for some purpose, that package is called a "Linux distribution" or "distro". There are a large handful of different teams of people that have created special Linux distributions designed to be installed on routers. I listed two of the most important router-focused Linux distributions. They don't all support the same models of routers, and there are many routers that no one has ever taken the time to create Linux support for. So you must check the supported router list for each Linux router firmware distro.

Comment: Apparently the R6700 has a secret telnet daemon that can be unlocked with a magic packet. https://openwrt.org/toh/netgear/telnet.console